# order is not working for structured property in app engine ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a model

```
from rated.lib import utility, data, money, search, kigo
class Property(ndb.Model):
  created_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = data.UTCDateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True, indexed=False)
  users = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)
  user = ndb.KeyProperty()
  rent_ = money.MoneyStructuredProperty(name='rent')
  rent = money.structured_value(rent_)
```

but when i try to get the records order by rent using query -

```
properties = Property.query().order(Property.rent)
```

It gives me the error -

```
TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order; received <super: <class 'structured_value'>, <structured_value object>>
```

structured_value is a class and it's syntax is --

```
class structured_value(object):
 def __init__(self, field):
    self.field = field

 def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    if instance is None:
        return super(structured_value, self).__get__(instance, owner)

    value = self.field.__get__(instance, owner)

    if value is None:
        return None

    if value.cached is None:
        value.cached = Money(value.value, value.currency)
    print
    return value.cached

 def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if value is None:
        self.field.__set__(instance, value)
        return

    model_value = MoneyModel(
        value=str(value.value),
        currency=value.currency
    )

    model_value.cached = value

    self.field.__set__(instance, model_value)
```

I am new to ndb, and wasted time to fix this thing......
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests you are not trying to order by a `property` or `Query order`.

What does `money.structured_value(rent_)` call return? and how do you think it will work ?

Based on your code `rent_` is what you should be ordering by, assuming your `MoneyStructuredProperty` is even orderable or ordered makes sense.

Ok, you have included the code for structured value and that is not how build a custom property, so of course you can't order by it.

Have a read up on building structured  properties, for starters they have to inherit from ndb.Model.